# Perform calculations using two RDDs in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So I have two RDD's

```
num_of_words = (doc_title,num) #number of words in a document
lines = (doc_title,word,num_of_occurrences) #number of occurrences of a specific word in a document
```

And I would like to find the term frequency, namely num_of_occurrences/number_of_words for each doc_title.

Is there an operation in Spark that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Spark, however this seems to be a rather straightforward task. Please correct me in the comments if I'm missing something.

Apply `join` transformation and then apply `map` to get the desired RDD

```
frequency = lines.join(num_words).map(x => x[0]/x[1])
```

Comment: I tried this, but lines.join(num_words) produced rows like (doc_title,(word,num)) while num_of_occurrences was omitted

Comment: @qwt185 What is the RDD you are trying to obtain. Is it (doc_title,word,num_of_occurences/num)?